# FFmpeg loglevel with level prefix

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-18.04

I want to add level prefix to ffmpeg logs.
Im using `ffmpeg -loglevel level+info -i input`
And it is working as well in my Mac (ios) but is not working in my Ubuntu 18 with ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

When I am running it in my Ubuntu I got:

```
Invalid loglevel "level+info". Possible levels are numbers or:
"quite"
"panic"
...
...
...
"trace"
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gyan's answer - The level flag was introduced in ffmpeg 4.

The solution is install FFmpeg 4 on Ubuntu by adding FFmpeg PPA on Ubuntu system acording to this guide: https://tecadmin.net/install-ffmpeg-on-linux/

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/ffmpeg-4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

The `level` flag was introduced in ffmpeg 4.0, so upgrade.

Comment: The only way to get ffmpeg 4 in ubuntu is using snap install ffmpeg and it is including ffplay under ffmpeg, something weird : "ffmpeg.ffplay" and is broken. You know something about it? I need normal usgae of ffplay command: "ffplay ....."